# Making text standout on detailed photos

Tags: text, composition

I'm looking for quick, yet professional looking ways of making text stand out on a photos which don't really have nice bland areas to put text. Something which would take an experienced photoshopper 5 minutes or less to do.

I found the image below as an example, but the text shadowing technique usually looks pretty amateurish.

What is typically done in advertising circles? Blurring of the image, dodging?

[image]

Comment: That question is for video which understandably might have to go for shadowed text. I would think static images have more techniques available to them.

Comment: If you're referring to static images, how is anyone able to answer? Each and every image or layout will require a different method. The only real answer is "use contrast".

Comment: Hence I said 'ways', or is it better to open up a question for each image? The two answers below were exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another, but maybe a bit dated, option is the 'selected text' look:

[image: example of selected text look on flyers]

YOu can use either a fully opaque or a partly translucent backdrop for the highlighting. In the 'if you can't get rid of it, flaunt it' spirit, you could go for a bright, contrasting colour for the highlight

Answer (score 2):

To just blur the part of the image that the text is over might look sloppy.

Take your example image - I would probably cut Jordan out of the image and blur the background a bit more, thus keeping him sharp. That will help the text.

I would also change the font to something more bold and maybe even change its colour.

EDIT

In other words, every image is different and it's usually a combination of things that produce the best result.